# converting system.object to int32 (powershell)

Tags: powershell

I have a variable:

```
$a =37,5 (System.Object[]).
```

how i can convert it to **int32** without fractional part (ex. Round to 38)? Thanks.

Comment: `[int] $( $a[0] )` might be more correct, unless your initial value should have been `37.5` instead of `37,5`?

Comment: The `,` character is not the decimal separator. That would be a dot (`.`).

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = 37,5 #<-- THIS IS ARRAY
[int]$a_int = [math]::Round($a -join ".")
$a_int

38

$a = 37.5 #<-- THIS IS FLOAT NUMBER
[int]$a_int = [math]::Round($a)
$a_int

38
```